# Java - ignore exception and continue with a return message

Tags: java, exception

In my java code if the `log()` method fails still want to proceed with the return of the response message, but the below code fails if the `log()` fails, i just want the code to work with a response
message irrespective of `log()` method fails or not.

My Code

```
public class MyClass 
{
    public MyResponse getMyResponse(MyRequest request) throws Exception
    {
        MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
        response=Service.getRes(request);
        log(request,response);
        return response;
    }

    public void log(MyRequest request,MyResponse response)
    {
        Service.log(request,response);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you detect if it failed or not?

Comment: Could you add try- catch block around log method, so that exception is caught and still code could continue?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [`finally`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-exception-handling/basic-try-catch-finally.html#finally).

```java
public MyResponse getMyResponse(MyRequest request) throws Exception
{
    MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
    response=Service.getRes(request);
    try {
        log(request,response);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Do something with the error?
    }
    finally {
        // No matter if there is an error or not, the following will be executed.
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: i get a warning "finally block does not complete normally" i assume finally should not have a return

Comment: You can put it after the catch block if you want, as long as you don't throw an exception in the catch block (if you do, your function wouldn't return anything anyway), whatever is after is also going to be executed no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

Use a **try-catch-finally** in log method. In *catch* you can do something about the error like print it(I suppose you cannot log it :) !) and in *finally* you continue with normal course of action.

Answer (score 0):

If by "fail" you mean that you are getting an exception, you could do this:

```
public void log(MyRequest request,MyResponse response)
{
    try { Service.log(request,response); } catch(Throwable e) {}
}
```

This will ignore any exception thrown by the Service.log request.